# Java service wrapper - Keep run and stopped

Tags: java, windows, service

This is the logs file, apprently the services work . The line file created is printed from my program. But it just fail to stay. What wrongs with my config ? been trying for a while but no clue

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/04/01 11:38:58 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/04/01 11:38:58 | file created
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2014/04/01 11:38:58 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/04/01 11:39:02 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/04/01 11:39:03 | file created
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2014/04/01 11:39:03 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/04/01 11:39:07 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2014/04/01 11:39:07 | file created
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2014/04/01 11:39:07 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/04/01 11:39:12 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/04/01 11:39:12 | file created
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2014/04/01 11:39:12 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/04/01 11:39:17 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/04/01 11:39:17 | file created
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2014/04/01 11:39:17 | JVM exited while loading the application.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/04/01 11:39:17 | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/04/01 11:39:17 |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/04/01 11:39:17 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

### Code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(3002);
        System.out.println("server started");
    try {
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = listener.accept();
            try {
                PrintWriter out =new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                out.println(new Date().toString()+"\ntest");
            } finally {
                socket.close();
            }
        }
    }
    finally {
        listener.close();
    }
}
```

### Conf file

```
#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Java Properties
#********************************************************************
# Java Application
#  Locate the java binary on the system PATH:
wrapper.java.command=java
#  Specify a specific java binary:
#set.JAVA_HOME=/java/path
#wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java

# Tell the Wrapper to log the full generated Java command line.
#wrapper.java.command.loglevel=INFO

# Java Main class.  This class must implement the WrapperListener interface
#  or guarantee that the WrapperManager class is initialized.  Helper
#  classes are provided to do this for you.  See the Integration section
#  of the documentation for details.
wrapper.java.mainclass=HelloWorldServer

# Java Classpath (include wrapper.jar)  Add class path elements as
#  needed starting from 1
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../lib/wrapper.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../lib/classes
wrapper.java.classpath.3=../dist/HelloWorldServer.jar

# Java Library Path (location of Wrapper.DLL or libwrapper.so)
wrapper.java.library.path.1=../lib

# Java Bits.  On applicable platforms, tells the JVM to run in 32 or 64-bit mode.
wrapper.java.additional.auto_bits=TRUE

# Java Additional Parameters
wrapper.java.additional.1=

# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.initmemory=3

# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.maxmemory=64

# Application parameters.  Add parameters as needed starting from 1
#wrapper.app.parameter.1=HelloWorldServer
```

Comment: You program is just writes to file and exit. It works exactly as it should. I'm not sure that do you expect here? Java wrapper is simple starter, that will not add any additional functionality to your code.

Comment: shouldnt it stay started after writing a file ?

Comment: No. Unless you tell it to. You can put something like `while(true) {Thread.sleep(1000)}`, then your program will never finish.

Comment: Ok now I changed my code , a socket with a while true loop, with this it will stay right ? as long as the service is running I am able to telnet that port am I right. But currently I am unable to start that services.Error : wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | server started
wrapper  | Startup failed: Timed out waiting for a signal from the JVM.

Comment: Check troubleshooting page: http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/troubleshooting.html#9 Do you get something like 100% CPU usage? Does your program runs without server wrappers?

Comment: yup it run w/o wrapper. it will stay running until i force close it

Comment: I follow the tutorial in the side as follows "http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/app-hello-world-server.html" even with their demo program, i am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set main class to one of [wrapper classes](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/integrate.html). Basically add following to your `wrapper.conf`:

```
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
wrapper.app.parameter.1=HelloWorldServer
```